# How to use the newest version of Ruby global on Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm new to Ruby and Linux and I wonder if this is possible?

I always have to work with:

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.2.1
```

when I want to work in a new directory.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any help appreciated!

Comment: If RVM isn't remembering your default across directories then there is something wrong with your installation. You don't say what your version is, but running `rvm get stable --auto` will upgrade to the latest version, along with updating "the user configuration files to the best known way of sourcing RVM."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set RVM to use that Ruby by default by using `rvm --default use 2.2.1`.
2. Use Brightbox's Ubuntu packages for Ruby, located at https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/

Comment: Ok thanks. But when i run `rvm --default use 2.2.1` then it's not global but only in this directory.

Comment: Is there really no simple way to use ruby 2.2.1 global on the system?

Comment: Option #2 will make it global on the system.